# Should particles in Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics (SPH) always move during a simulation?

Tags: computational-physics, diffusion

Or can they just be used as an interpolation points and use some other "transported property" which are just evolved and propagated from boundary conditions like for eg. heat conduction through a solid metal bar. It seems to be possible, but isn't clearly elaborated. The force computation step is always used for fluid flow to move particles forward according to Newton's laws, but what if heat is transported purely by conduction in a solid? Here, nothing moves but still, heat flows and destroys temperature gradients. What equations are to be considered here (apart from the heat diffusion equation) to adapt this problem for this kind of discretization?

Comment: This might be better suited for scicomp.stackexchange.com than here...

Comment: No problem, but you may want to edit your post and put "Cross listed at: <scicomp url>" (where you'd actually put the url to the scicomp question there).